# EntityManager NULL en un servicio REST usando resteasy, jboss seam 2.1.1 y JBoss AS 4.2.2

Tags: java, rest, jboss, seam

tengo un problema en una aplicación web desarrollada con jboss seam 2.1.1 y usando JBoss AS 4.2.2 como servidor de aplicaciones. Estoy tratando de brindar un servicio REST usando la librería resteasy-jaxrs-2.1.0.GA, jboss-seam-resteasy-2.3.1.Final y jaxrs-api-2.1.0.GA y resulta que cada vez que consumo el servicio, el entityManager está NULL, debajo voy a poner cada una de las configuraciones y clases:

Tengo creado el beans.xml dentro del WEB-INF, mi configuración en el web.xml dentro del WEB-INF es la siguiente:

```
<!-- Auto scan REST service -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>paquetea.paqueteb.ClaseA</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
     <listener-class>
         org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
     </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>paquetea.JaxRsActivator</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

La clase JaxRsActivator es la siguiente:

```
package paquetea;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {



}
```

Esta es la clase con el servicio donde están los Endpoints, con los nombres cambiados debido a que no puedo exponer la clase real:

```
package paquetea.paqueteb;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;



@Name("claseA")
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
@Path("/clasea")
@Stateless
public class ClaseA {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "contexto")  
    EntityManager entityManager;




    @GET
    @Path("/ejemplo/{fecha}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test(@PathParam("fecha") String fecha)
    {       
        try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d");
            Date date = formatter.parse(fecha);

            EntityManager em = this.entityManager; //Esto es para comprobar si el entityManager no está null, y siempre que se accede está NULL.
            /*Aqui se consulta una logica en otra clase que tambien tiene un entityManage inyectado y siempre es NULL*/
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return "la respuesta";
    }




 }
```

Esta es la configuración en el components.xml dentro de WEB-INF del contexto de persistencia para que el entityManager se cree de forma automática al iniciar la aplicación, esto funciona correctamente en el resto de la aplicación web, el problema solo pasa en el servicio rest:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
                                 auto-create="true"
                  persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/ejemploEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

Y esta es la configuración de mi Unidad de Persistencia o PersistenceUnit:

```
<persistence-unit name="contexto">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:/ejemploDatasource</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider"/>

     <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/ejemploEntityManagerFactory"/>

     <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="paquetex.TimerInterceptor" />
  </properties>
```

Espero por su ayuda pues ya lo he intentado todo, he buscado en todos los foros todo lo relacionado con este problema y no me funciona. 
La JVM que usamos es la 1.6_24 pues el proyecto es una aplicación desarrollada hace un tiempo ya.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero ¿no debería injectar el EntityManager en la ClaseA?

Comment: Gracias por responder, si, lo he hecho de esa forma también, e inyectado el entityManager de la siguiente forma y siempre es NULL: @In EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: No sé que hacer, cosas parecidas me han pasado - no poder injectar un bean, y lo único que me ha funcionado es pasar el bean como parámetro en un constructor. No sé, prueba.

Comment: Y cómo le pasarías a la Clase A que es el servicio rest el bean y desde dónde y en qué momento?